# Cannot Edit/Move/Transfer files via SCP to Linux Server

Tags: debian, scp

I have a Linux server running Debian 9 to which I am trying to send/edit files to via WinSCP from my Windows machine. I am authenticating the connection via the SCP protocol with a user named: ASCUSER. Here is the permission/group information for ASCUSER:

```
/etc/apache2$ id -nG ascuser
ascuser root adm sudo www-data plugdev netdev lpadmin wwwpub
```

And here are the permissions/group accesses files I am trying to manipulate:
Directory: /etc/apache2

```
/etc$ ls -l apache2
total 88
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7224 Sep 19  2017 apache2.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17  2019 conf-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 19  2018 conf-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1782 Sep 19  2017 envvars
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31063 Sep 19  2017 magic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Mar 11  2020 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 20  2019 mods-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   320 Jul 10  2018 ports.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   323 Jul 10  2018 ports.conf~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 17  2019 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 20  2019 sites-enabled
```

Specifically apache2.conf. From my understanding both the owner (root) and the group (root) should have access to this file and given that ASCUSER is a part of the root group, I believe it should have access too. However anytime I try to edit the file externally and internally, or attempt to I get an access denied error:

```
Copying file 'a long temporary file address to where windows stores scp related temp files for scp transfer' failed.
scp: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Permission denied`
```

I'm not sure what I am missing at this point?

Answer (score 2):

See

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7224 Sep 19  2017 apache2.conf
    ^^
```

Group root has the permission to read the file but not to write it, so user `ascuser` cannot edit the file.